# Conflicting jars while using Unirest on CDH

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, unirest

I'm trying to use Unirest to send a POST request from a MapReduce job on a Cloudera Hadoop 5.2.1 cluster.

One of Unirest's dependencies is `httpcore-4.3.3.jar`. The CDH package includes `httpcore-4.2.5.jar` in the classpath. While trying to run my code, I got a "ClassNotFound" exception.

I added a line in my code to check where it's getting a different class from and the answer was troubling: `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/httpcore-4.2.5.jar`.

I've looked everywhere online and tried everything I found. Needless to say, nothing seems to work.

I tried setting HADOOP_CLASSPATH environment variable, I tried setting HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST, and I tried using the -libjars parameter in the hadoop jar command.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?